# regex how to replace all square brackets and content inside it with blank

Tags: java, regex, file-io

I have a file name as `AcbsIncorSigRemover[1.1].java`

I want to rename this file as `AcbsIncorSigRemover.java`

Can you provide me with valid regex validation?

I have thousands of files like this that need to be renamed. Please help.

Comment: Show us what you tried

Comment: If you are getting file-name as string and just want to alter the `String` then you can do it even without using `RE`.

Comment: I am getting the name as a string..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
"AcbsIncorSigRemover[1.1].java".replaceAll("\\[(.*?)\\]","")
```

output

```
AcbsIncorSigRemover.java
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/O9JqJN)

Answer (score -3):

```
 String s = "AcbsIncorSigRemover[1.1].java";    
 s= s.substring(0,s.indexOf("["))+".java";
```